# How to select rows based on left quantity

Tags: sql

I've been trying to make a Select statement using data from two tables that will return only products in stock and I'm having trouble with that. 
I have 2 tables. One lists Products, another Orders. Data in Products is static.

tables are created using these lines

```
create table Products (ProductID integer, TotalQuantity integer);
insert into Products values (1, 1);
insert into Products values (2, 2);
insert into Products values (3, 20);
insert into Products values (4, 10);
insert into Products values (5, 20);
insert into Products values (6, 10);
insert into Products values (7, 5);
insert into Products values (8, 50);
insert into Products values (9, 1);

create table Orders (OrderID integer, ProductID integer, Amount integer);
insert into Orders values (6, 4, 1);
insert into Orders values (6, 6, 1);
insert into Orders values (6, 1, 1);
insert into Orders values (47, 4, 1);
insert into Orders values (6, 9, 1);
insert into Orders values (5, 7, 1);
insert into Orders values (6, 2, 2);
```

And tables look like this (if this is more easily viewable

Products table
[image: Products table]

Orders Table
[image: Orders table]

I have achieved partial success with a following query

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.TotalQuantity 
FROM Products p 
JOIN Orders o
ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID, o.Amount, p.TotalQuantity
HAVING SUM(o.Amount) < p.TotalQuantity
```

But that only returns the results for products that had been ordered. Those that HAVE'NT are not included (should get products with id 3, 5, 8).

I've read that I can combine 2 select queries into one, but I have no idea how to get not ordered products too.

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.TotalQuantity 
FROM Products p 
JOIN Orders o
ON o.ProductID != p.ProductID
```

This does not return expected values.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using (although it does not affect the answer in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your method, you can continue with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.TotalQuantity 
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ProductID, o.Amount, p.TotalQuantity
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(o.Amount), 0) < p.TotalQuantity;
```

Another way to write this would be with a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
WHERE p.TotalQuantity > (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(o.Amount), 0)
                         FROM Orders o
                         WHERE o.ProductID = p.ProductID
                        );
```

Under many circumstances (i.e. an index on `Orders(ProductID, Amount)`), this will have better performance because it does not require aggregating all the data at once.

Comment: so in second example i would need to use coalesce somewhere too then to get same result as the first case? `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(o.Amount), 0)`

Comment: @NulisDefo . . . Good catch.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the second example works exactly? I've never encountered  COALESCE before. And in this case it seems a bit confusing to me. The second query calculating sum would go through each p.ProductID and compare to first query. When it reaches p.ProductID = 3, o.ProductID has no equivalent or in other words result is NULL and thus instead it changes it so that there is some result (namely 0) and compares that zero with p.TotalQuantity where p.ProductID = 3. Do i understand correctly?

Comment: @NulisDefo . . . Google "<your database> correlated subquery".  It is covered well in most database documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to achieve the results.
You need to add a WHERE clause after your ON that tells the SQL to only return parts with a TotalQuantity greater than 0.

You could also add the p.TotalQuantity > 0 to the ON statement.

Comment: It's always TotalQuantity > 0. TotalQuantity represents the number of products that is still nto sent away